# SQL Joins and Conditional Sums

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum, inner-join

I have two tables which are set up as follows:

`PMmx` - a table version of an origin-destination matrix

```
Origin  Destination Trips
1           1        0.2
2           1        0.3
3           1        0.4
.           .         .
.           .         .
1         1101       0.6
2         1101       0.7
3         1101       0.8
.          .          .
.          .          .     
1101       1         0.2
1101       2         0.3
1101       3         0.4
```

`ZE` - a table with zone equivalences

```
Precinct    Zone
1           1101
2           1102
3           1111
```

I would like to select the row entries in the `PMmx` table which match the `Zone` column in the `ZE` table. For example:

```
Origin  Destination Trips
1         1101       0.6
2         1101       0.7
3         1101       0.8
.          .          .
.          .          .     
1101       1         0.2
1101       2         0.3
1101       3         0.4
```

I would also like to create a new column called `Distribution` which calculates the `Trips/(Total Trips)` where the total trips will be summed over the specific zone number (by either `Origin` or `Destination` depending which column matches the zone equivalence `Zone` number).

For example, for `Origin` 1, `Destination` 1101, I want the new `Distribution` value for that row entry to be `0.6/(0.6+0.7+0.8)`.

I have tried the following code

```
SELECT 
      PMmx.Origin                  as Origin
     ,PMmx.Destination             as Destination
     ,PMmx.Trips/sum(PMmx.Trips) as 'Distribution'
FROM PMmx

inner join ZE on Origin=ZE.Zone or Destination=ZE.Zone 

Group by Origin, Destination, Trips
```

I am unsure if this will produce correct results as without the group by clause I get `Column '2DVISUM_2031PMmx_unpiv.Origin' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` And with the group by clause I get `Divide by zero error encountered.`

From the `inner join` there shouldn't be any `sums` which would be zero so I am unsure why I am getting this error.

Please help!

**EDIT:** I am getting duplicate rows now using the query

```
with cte as (
  select
     origin, destination, trips
  , SUM(Trips) over(partition by Pmx.Origin) sum_trips
  , trips / SUM(Trips) over(partition by Pmx.Origin) trips_div
  from Pmx
  inner join ZE on Pmx.Origin = ZE.Zone
  )
select
origin, destination, trips, sum_trips, trips_div
from cte
union all
select
destination, origin, trips, sum_trips, trips_div
from cte
```

Updated tables to show error:

ZE:

```
Precinct    Zone    
1           1101    
2           1102    
3           1111    
4           1211
```

Pmx:

```
Origin  Destination Trips
1           1       0.20
2           1       0.30
3           1       0.40
1          1101     0.60
2          1101     0.70
3          1101     0.80
1101        1       0.20
1101        2       0.30
1101        3       0.40
1101       1211     0.60
1211       1101     0.50
```

Output containing duplicates with different trip values:

```
origin destination trips sum_trips trips_div

1101    1   0.20    1.50    0.13333333333333333333333333
1101    2   0.30    1.50    0.20000000000000000000000000
1101    3   0.40    1.50    0.26666666666666666666666666
1101  1211  0.60    1.50    0.40000000000000000000000000
1211  1101  0.50    0.50    1.00000000000000000000000000
1     1101  0.20    1.50    0.13333333333333333333333333
2     1101  0.30    1.50    0.20000000000000000000000000
3     1101  0.40    1.50    0.26666666666666666666666666
1211  1101  0.60    1.50    0.40000000000000000000000000
1101  1211  0.50    0.50    1.00000000000000000000000000
```

**EDIT 2:** I am wanting to create an 'if statement' so that if the `Pmx.origin =ZE.Zone` then `trips_div` is `trips/SUM(Trips) over(partition by Pmx.Origin)` as above. However, if `Pmx.origin =ZE.Zone` and `Pmx.destination=ZE.Zone` then I want `trips_div` to still be `trips/SUM(Trips) over(partition by Pmx.Origin)`. When `Pmx.origin does not equal ZE.Zone` and `Pmx.destination=ZE.Zone` then `trips/SUM(Trips) over(partition by Pmx.Destination)`. I have tried a variety of `case when` statements but cannot seem to get it to work.

I would like the output to be:

```
origin destination trips sum_trips trips_div

    1     1101  0.20    2.10    0.0952380952380952
    2     1101  0.30    2.10    0.1428571428571429
    3     1101  0.40    2.10    0.1904761904761905
    1101    1   0.20    1.50    0.1333333333333333
    1101    2   0.30    1.50    0.2000000000000000
    1101    3   0.40    1.50    0.2666666666666666
    1101  1211  0.60    1.50    0.4000000000000000
    1211  1101  0.50    0.50    1.0000000000000000
```

Comment: response to your "edit 2" see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e8020/6 that case expression is `case when Pmx.origin <> ZE.Zone and Pmx.destination = ZE.Zone then trips/SUM(Trips) over(partition by Pmx.Destination)
     else trips/SUM(Trips) over(partition by Pmx.Origin)
    end`  but it makes no difference to the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement I think you can use a slightly different approach for the sum which makes that sum available on each row of the source table. With this you don't need the group by clause.

```
SELECT 
       PMmx.Origin                  as Origin
     , PMmx.Destination             as Destination
     , (PMmx.Trips/sum(PMmx.Trips) over(partition by Destination)) as 'Distribution'
FROM PMmx
inner join ZE on Origin=ZE.Zone or Destination=ZE.Zone
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e8020/4)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Pmx
    ([Origin] int, [Destination] int, [Trips] decimal(12,2))
;
    
INSERT INTO Pmx
    ([Origin], [Destination], [Trips])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 0.2),
    (2, 1, 0.3),
    (3, 1, 0.4),
    (1, 1101, 0.6),
    (2, 1101, 0.7),
    (3, 1101, 0.8),
    (1101, 1, 0.2),
    (1101, 2, 0.3),
    (1101, 3, 0.4)
;


CREATE TABLE ZE
    ([Precinct] int, [Zone] int)
;
    
INSERT INTO ZE
    ([Precinct], [Zone])
VALUES
    (1, 1101),
    (2, 1102),
    (3, 1111)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
with cte as (
  select
     origin, destination, trips
  , SUM(Trips) over(partition by Pmx.Origin) sum_trips
  , trips / SUM(Trips) over(partition by Pmx.Origin) trips_div
  from Pmx
  inner join ZE on Pmx.Origin = ZE.Zone
  )
select
origin, destination, trips, sum_trips, trips_div
from cte
union -- changed to union so duplication is avoided
select
destination, origin, trips, sum_trips, trips_div
from cte
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e8020/4/0)**:

```
| origin | destination | trips | sum_trips |          trips_div |
|--------|-------------|-------|-----------|--------------------|
|   1101 |           1 |   0.2 |       0.9 | 0.2222222222222222 |
|   1101 |           2 |   0.3 |       0.9 | 0.3333333333333333 |
|   1101 |           3 |   0.4 |       0.9 | 0.4444444444444444 |
|      1 |        1101 |   0.2 |       0.9 | 0.2222222222222222 |
|      2 |        1101 |   0.3 |       0.9 | 0.3333333333333333 |
|      3 |        1101 |   0.4 |       0.9 | 0.4444444444444444 |
```

---

## part 2

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/82eb9/2)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Pmx
    ([Origin] int, [Destination] int, [Trips] decimal(12,2))
;
    
INSERT INTO Pmx
    ([Origin], [Destination], [Trips])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 0.20),
    (2, 1, 0.30),
    (3, 1, 0.40),
    (1, 1101, 0.60),
    (2, 1101, 0.70),
    (3, 1101, 0.80),
    (1101, 1, 0.20),
    (1101, 2, 0.30),
    (1101, 3, 0.40),
    (1101, 1211, 0.60),
    (1211, 1101, 0.50)
;


CREATE TABLE ZE
    ([Precinct] int, [Zone] int)
;
    
INSERT INTO ZE
    ([Precinct], [Zone])
VALUES
    (1, 1101),
    (2, 1102),
    (3, 1111),
    (4, 1211)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
with cte as (
  select
     origin, destination, trips
  , SUM(Trips) over(partition by Pmx.Origin) sum_trips
  , trips / SUM(Trips) over(partition by Pmx.Origin) trips_div
  from Pmx
  inner join ZE on Pmx.Origin = ZE.Zone
  )
select
origin, destination, trips, sum_trips, trips_div
from cte
union
select
destination, origin, trips, sum_trips, trips_div
from cte
order by 1,2,3,4
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/82eb9/2/0)**:

```
| origin | destination | trips | sum_trips |           trips_div |
|--------|-------------|-------|-----------|---------------------|
|      1 |        1101 |   0.2 |       1.5 | 0.13333333333333333 |
|      2 |        1101 |   0.3 |       1.5 |                 0.2 |
|      3 |        1101 |   0.4 |       1.5 | 0.26666666666666666 |
|   1101 |           1 |   0.2 |       1.5 | 0.13333333333333333 |
|   1101 |           2 |   0.3 |       1.5 |                 0.2 |
|   1101 |           3 |   0.4 |       1.5 | 0.26666666666666666 |
|   1101 |        1211 |   0.5 |       0.5 |                   1 |
|   1101 |        1211 |   0.6 |       1.5 |                 0.4 |
|   1211 |        1101 |   0.5 |       0.5 |                   1 |
|   1211 |        1101 |   0.6 |       1.5 |                 0.4 |
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up breaking my problem into multiple tables when I was stuck on how to do it properly and somehow ended up with repeated rows (must be from incorrect joining). Once reading your post I have re-done it in this way and it all seems to work! Thank you!

Comment: I spoke too soon @Used_By_Already ! I seem to be getting duplicate rows now for entries where the origin and destination both match up to the equivalence table ZE. For example in the Pmx when Origin is 1101 and destination is 1102. I can't seem to see why this is happening?

Comment: I  dont know can you add sample data that allows the problem to be replicated.

Comment: It seems that with query 1 as above I get two rows for origin 1101 destination 1102 as the trips appear as different because it is taking the trips from the origin 1102 destination 1101 entry and listing it as origin 1101 destination 1102. OK, I will add some more data now.

Comment: I have updated my question with an edit at the end - thanks @Used_By_Already !

Comment: I still get the same issue when changing from union all to union :( @Used_By_Already

Comment: It really isn't possible for union to return duplicated rows, so I'm afraid I don't know what the problem is now. I cannot replicate the problem either (see "part 2 in the answer" and I get 10 unique rows with "union all" or "union". Without the ability to replicate whatever the problem is I cannot solve it.

Comment: In your Part 2 results section you are replicating the duplicate issue. See how in the last 4 rows there are repeated entries for origin 1101 destination 1211 which should only have one row with trip equal to 0.6; and also for origin 1211 and destination 1101 which should only have one row with trips equal to 0.5.

Comment: "duplicate" is an "exact copy of whole row" not part of a row.  I see no duplicates at all.  This data is given in table `Pmx`     (1101, 1211, 0.60),
    (1211, 1101, 0.50) so I fail to understand how I should magically make that one row, Check and double check the data.

Comment: Apologies with the terminology and if I wasn't clear in my question. For the row (1101,1211,0.6), I would only want one row which contains (1101,1211,0.6,1.5,0.4) when including Distribution. Therefore, I am asking that the sum(Trips) be only the sum of trips for 1101 not 1211 as well which would produce the two different rows for origin 1101 and destination 1211. I.e. sum(Trips) refers to the either Origin or Destination depending on the zone number matching. However, if both Origin and Destination are contained within the zone equivalence table then sum(Trips) will prioritise the Origin sum.

Comment: `"I would only want one row"` that's great, but how will I write a query to read your mind? You need to think about how a query will exclude the unwanted row(s) and once that is understood use a where clause to include only the rows you do want. I cannot write this because you are the only one with the necessary understanding of the data and of the requirement.

Comment: I have added a second edit to my question which explains what I am after. If it is unclear please let me know. I am new to this forum and also to SQL so please bear with me as I try and figure out the best way to communicate everything. Thanks :)